# Adding columns to SQLite table doesn't use the full item name

Tags: c#, winforms, sqlite

I have a SQLite database with a Table called Reports. No what i want to do is add columns for the products not already in the table.

So it goes through the report the table and check if the product column is there or not and if it isn't, it adds the column.

Here is the code:

```
using Stock_A_Lot.BAL;
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Stock_A_Lot.PL
{
public partial class Report_Form : Form
{
    DBHelper db = new DBHelper();
    Database_Handler dbh = new Database_Handler();
    public Report_Form()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable Prods;
        String query = "Select ProdDesc From Product";
        Prods = db.GetDataTable(query);

        DataTable Report;
        String queryReport = "Select * From Report";
        Report = db.GetDataTable(queryReport);

        foreach(DataRow dr in Prods.Rows)
        {
            ContainColumn(dr[0].ToString() + "Curr", Report);
            ContainColumn(dr[0].ToString() + "Prev", Report);
        }
    }

    private void ContainColumn(string columnName, DataTable table)
    {
        DataColumnCollection columns = table.Columns;

        if (columns.Contains(columnName))
        {

        }
        else
        {
            string query = "ALTER TABLE Report ADD COLUMN " + columnName + " TEXT DEFAULT '0';";
            dbh.updatereportable(query);
        }
    }
}
```

}

But when it runs, it only uses the first word of a product name, for example:
Black label will only be read as Black, then it throws an error saying "duplicate column name: black".

I don't know if i'm missing something or what. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your query if `columnname` have space in it like `test column` then it will fail with that error. Try escaping it saying

```
"ALTER TABLE Report ADD COLUMN \"" + columnName + "\"  TEXT DEFAULT '0'";
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to put [] around the column name?

`string query = "ALTER TABLE Report ADD COLUMN [" + columnName + "] TEXT DEFAULT '0';";`